# Select Stored procedure query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select certain stored procedures within my database.

What I want is all stored procedures that start with `Get_` but I cannot get proper results. It seems to ignore the `_` for some reason.  Running SQL Server 2019 developer version.

Here is my code:

```
select * 
from information_schema.routines 
where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE' and specific_name like 'Get_%'
```

Comment: Side point: you shouldn't use `information_schema`, it's for compatibility only. Instead use `sys.procedures`

Comment: @ charlieface gives me an error ?

Comment: What's the error?  You'll have to change the columns names in the WHERE clause since they're different between INFORMATION_SCHEMA objects and sys objects.

Comment: `select * from sys.procedures p where p.name like 'Get[_]%'`

Comment: I read the other question and it seems a bit different to me?  anyone else think so?

Comment: @duerzd696 No, I agree with the duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underscore `_` character is a wildcard in SQL Server t-sql.  Use `LIKE 'Get[_]%'` to explictly match an actual underscore in the string.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/wildcard-character-s-to-match-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - "[ ] (Wildcard - Character(s) to Match)":

> Matches any single character within the specified range or set that is
> specified between brackets [ ]. These wildcard characters can be used
> in string comparisons that involve pattern matching, such as LIKE and
> PATINDEX.